# Importing a simple variable from the useContext hook using ApolloClient

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm relatively new to react and can't seem to import a `client` variable from a context. I have a file called federation.tsx with some code, where I believe this should be the relevant part:

```
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: process.env.URL,
});

const useApolloClient = (user: User | null) => {
  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        Authorization: user?.idToken || "",
      },
    };
  });
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(link as any),
    cache: cache,
    name: "Test",
    version: process.env.ANOTHER_URL,
  });
};

export const FederationProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  const [acc] = useContext(UserContext);
  const client = useApolloClient(acc);
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};
```

And my main app file with the context provider wrapping everything relevant:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
            <FederationProvider>
                  <Router>
                    <Routes/>
                  </Router>
            </FederationProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the file where I try to use it:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from "react";
import {FederationProvider} from "..src";

export const someComponent(() => {
    const [client] = useContext(FederationProvider); // not working

    return (<>...</>)
})
```

Can anyone spot anything obvious that I may have done incorrectly? I'm not sure how to simply just import the client variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs, it says to use the client configured via a `ApolloProvider` by using the `useApolloClient` hook like so :-

`const client = useApolloClient();`

Docs - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#useapolloclient