# How to get access to `client` object anywhere in the app with Apollo Client?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a basic app using Apollo Client v1:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({...

...

<ApolloProvider client={client}>
   <App />
</ApolloProvider>,
```

i was wondering how i could give the rest of my app access to the `client` object so that they can make queries using `client.query`?

Is the only way to export client and then import it in another file?

Since my app is wrapped in a `ApolloProvider`, I figured there might be a way of importing `client` using an Apollo specific import?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing a simple variable from the useContext hook using ApolloClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314448/importing-a-simple-variable-from-the-usecontext-hook-using-apolloclient)

Answer (score 15):

```
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

function SomeComponent() {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  // `client` is now set to the `ApolloClient` instance being used by the
  // application (that was configured using something like `ApolloProvider`)
}
```

Comment: this doesn't get the client from the ApolloProvider. I can confirm as the HttpLink being used by this client is diff than the one set in ApolloProvider.